# How to define custom handling for a response class in Spring doc?

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I've been using arrow-kt and spring together a lot lately. I've actually constructed a bridge between the two with several key features, one of which is a spring controller that returns an Either will automatically unwrap it and either handle the exception (Left) or return the result (Right). My long term goal is to publish this as a library.

My latest obstacle is Swagger, or more accurately springdoc openapi. Obviously it is seeing the Either, but i want it to show only the Right value as the success response type. While I know there are annotations where I can set the response model on each controller method individually, I'm trying to avoid this.

My real goal is to setup some global converter so that wherever Swagger sees an Either it will automatically unpack this. I'm just not super familiar with the customization API in Spring doc, and everything I Google just points me to the ApiResponse annotation solution.

How can I define default handling for this type of response?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.